# How to sort out a text file in python using numbers in the text file

Tags: python

I have the following text file:

```
345 eee
12 nt
3 s
9 test
```

How can I make it so it sorts it in numerical order with the text there?

The output I'm hoping for is

```
345 eee
12 nt
9 test
3 s
```

Note: I'm grabbing data from text files

```
45 eee
12 nt
945 test
344 s
45 gh
```

> **Current Code**
>   Credit: @CypherX

```
import pandas as pd

s = """
345 eee
1200 nt
9 test
-3 s
"""

# Custom Function
def sort_with_digits(s, ascending = True):
    lines = s.strip().split('\n')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Lines': lines})
    df2 = df.Lines.str.strip().str.split(' ', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'Numbers', 1: 'Text'})
    df['Numbers'] = df2['Numbers'].astype(float)
    df['Text'] = df2['Text'].str.strip()
    df.sort_values(['Numbers', 'Text'], ascending = ascending, inplace=True)
    return df.Lines.tolist()

print(s)
sort_with_digits(s, ascending = True) # this is your output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python and no system calls:

```
# This is the function to amend when you want to change the ordering
def key_function(line):
    # To sort by the first number when there is a space
    return int(line.split()[0])
```

To extract any number that begins the line you can use a regex

```
def key_function(line):
    match = re.match('^\d+', line)
    if match:
        return int(match.group())
    else:
        return 0
```

Then the rest of the method is the same

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    # Read all lines into a list
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    # Sort all the lines by "key_function"
    for line in sorted(lines, key=key_function, reverse=True):
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Is it possible to numerically order it?

Comment: @ZacIsa by the first number in each line?

Comment: Just using the numbers untils theres a a space. For example '12-test'. The '-' being the space

Comment: Added a regex that should do what you need. `^\d+` matches any digits at the start of a string and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in bash. you can use subprocess to run it in python.

```
sort -k1 -r -n file > new_file
```

Using this with pyhton subprocess

```
import subprocess

# Simple command
subprocess.Popen(['sort -k1 -r -n test.txt'], shell=True)
```

Comment: How would I use this if my file was called 'Text.txt'?

Comment: sameway just text.txt > new_text.txt

Comment: How could I use it in a python script?

Comment: As i said, subprocess is one way to go. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @ZacIsa i edited the post to show you a python subprocess example.

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT**: 
>   The OP described later that the requirement is to first order by numbers and then order by the rest of text that follows. The solution now reflects this requirement.

---

> I wrote a custom function (`sort_with_digits`) which finds out the numbers and then sorts the lines accordingly using **`pandas`** library. All you have to do is:

```py
#read-in data from a text file:
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
sort_with_digits(s, ascending = True)
```

## Code with Example Data

```py
s = """
345 eee
12 nt
9 test
3 s
"""

import pandas as pd

# Custom Function
def sort_with_digits(s, ascending = True):
    lines = s.strip().split('\n')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Lines': lines})
    df2 = df.Lines.str.strip().str.split(' ', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'Numbers', 1: 'Text'})
    df['Numbers'] = df2['Numbers'].astype(float)
    df['Text'] = df2['Text'].str.strip()
    df.sort_values(['Numbers', 'Text'], ascending = ascending, inplace=True)
    return df.Lines.tolist()

sort_with_digits(s, ascending = True)
```

**Output**:

```
['3 s', '9 test', '12 nt', '345 eee']
```

> **Note:** 
>   If you use a simple `'\n'.join(result)` on a list (`result`) that will produce a string formatted similar to out the input (`s`).

```py
result = sort_with_digits(s, ascending = True)
print('\n'.join(result))
```

**Output**:

```
12 nt
45 eee
45 gh
344 s
945 test
```

### With Another Dummy Dataset

1. Dummy Data: A

```py
s = """
345 eee
1200 nt
9 test
-3 s
"""

# Expected Result: ['-3 s', '9 test', '345 eee', '1200 nt']
# And the solution produces this as well.
```

2. Dummy Data: B

```py
s = """
45 eee
12 nt
945 test
344 s
45 gh
"""

# Expected Result: ['12 nt', '45 eee', '45 gh', '344 s', '945 test']
# And the solution produces this as well.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205400/discussion-on-answer-by-cypherx-how-to-sort-out-a-text-file-in-python-using-numb).

Comment: Thanks @SamuelLiew. I saw the option for moving to the chat once. But later it was not available any more.

Answer (score -1):

All right, here's a bad answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

os.system('sort -n -r /path/to/file')
```

I used python to run a shell command "sort" using the numeric and reverse options.

I used python because you tagged the question python.

I used the -r option because your output example seems to be sorted in reverse order.

This would be a better answer if it used subprocess instead of os.system (as the other answer mentions).

Comment: The OP was looking for (native) Python code. Also this will break on Windows.